# Regexp парсинг одной определенной ссылки из текста

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть некий текст, например:

```
"img": "https://militaryarms.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/yupiter.jpg",
"imgBig": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/Jupiter_and_its_shrunken_Great_Red_Spot.jpg",
"img2": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Neptune_-_Voyager_2_%2829347980845%29_flatten_crop.jpg",
"imgBig2": "https://s14.stc.all.kpcdn.net/share/i/12/10545250/inx960x640.jpg",
```

Из него нужно спарсить regexp'ом только imgBig ссылку без кавычек, то есть

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/Jupiter_and_its_shrunken_Great_Red_Spot.jpg
```

`(https?://\S+)` не помог, т.к. выделяет все ссылки вместе с запятыми.
Также ссылки могут быть любыми.

Есть ли возможность выделить определенную ссылку по номеру совпадения? Или можно выделять по названию строки imgBig?

Comment: `\"imgBig\":\s*\"([^\"]+)?\"`

Comment: Спасибо, а если нужно чтобы выделялось до .jpg?

Comment: `\"imgBig\":\s*\"([^\"]+)?\.jpg\"`

Comment: Благодарю, вопрос можно считать закрытым

Comment: @splash58 Не желаете оформить как ответ?

Comment: @nomnoms12 да, мне кажется, слишком стандартный вопрос, чтобы отвечать, достаточно комментария :)